# Calculate primary winding current in transformer under load[Exercise]

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, single-phase, winding

I have been trying to get to the answer to this exercise shown in the Solutions' reference page but despite countless attempts couldn't get to it.

it reads as follows:

```
A 100 kVA, 10000/120 single phase transformer is supplying
    75 kVA under no load,(edit: FULL LOAD has PF=0.8 and 100 kVA)
    with a power factor = 0.8. 

OC and SC test results are as follows:    

    OC: Nominal primary voltage
        P0 = 1kW
        I0 = 0.85 A

    SC: Nominal secondary current
        Pcc = 1.6kW
        Vcc = 430 V
```

Question: Calculate the transformer's primary winding current

```
Solution according to reference page: I1= 8.12 A
```

Any hint to pop me up?

Regards

Comment: Pressing enter halfway on long lines of text makes things so much easier to read.

Comment: How can it both be supplying 75 kVA under no load with PF 0.8 AND be only taking 1 kW on an open circuit test?

Comment: @Andyaka because it is a homework problem?

Comment: @R.Johnson - the question is contradictory

Comment: I think it means that when there is no load you have 75 kVA. When there is load you have 100 kVA with PF = 0.8

Comment: @R.Johnson don't misjudge so quickly. I'm not in highschool or whatsoever. This is not homework, I don't have to report this to a teacher or tutor or whatever you want to name it. This is self-studying just for myself to be able to pass a final exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution. I'm still not sure how it was done, but I wanted to share it just in case.
[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer but an explanation of the contradictory nature of the question and is too long to leave as a coherent comment.

Power factor: -

[image]

If no load apparent power is 75 kVA and power factor is 0.8 then the working power HAS to be 60 kW i.e. 0.8 x 75.

If the no load working power draw is 60 kW then, the open circuit (OC) test cannot produce a power of only 1 kW.

*An open circuit test IS a no-load test AND it is done at the nominal supply voltage of the primary hence you can't have 75 kVA at 0.8 PF (60 kW) and 1 kW.*

The question is flawed.

Comment: I think it means that when there is no load you have 75 kVA. When there is load you have 100 kVA with PF = 0.8

Comment: Excuse the poor translation of this exercise. source language is spanish and I am not used to translating technical text.